# Why supervisor is processing one job more than once?

Tags: laravel-5, ubuntu-14.04, supervisord, laravel-queue

I've been working on a [Laravel (5.3)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/) project in which I have to crawl data from multiple websites.

So, for that I set up [queue jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues) and configured a [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) for them.

Everything works fine until I configure the supervisor to run only 1 process.

In file

> /etc/supervisor/conf.d/laravel-worker.conf

```
numprocs=1
```

When I assign the numprocs value to more than 1, it behaves weird that supervisor executes the jobs for 2 times or 3 times.

Followings are my versions:

- Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
- Laravel 5.3
- supervisord 3.0b2

Followings are my configurations:

Configurations for following file are

> /etc/supervisor/supervisor.conf

```
; supervisor config file

[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0700                       ; sockef file mode (default 0700)

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)

; the below section must remain in the config file for RPC
; (supervisorctl/web interface) to work, additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate rpcinterface: sections
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

; The [include] section can just contain the "files" setting.  This
; setting can list multiple files (separated by whitespace or
; newlines).  It can also contain wildcards.  The filenames are
; interpreted as relative to this file.  Included files *cannot*
; include files themselves.

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

Configurations for following file are

> /etc/supervisor/conf.d/laravel-worker.conf

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/myapp/artisan queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=hmabuzar
numprocs=25
redirect_stderr=true
stderr_events_enabled=true
stderr_logfile=/var/www/myapp/storage/logs/worker.error.log
stdout_logfile=/var/www/myapp/storage/logs/worker.log
```

Comment: This question looks similar to https://serverfault.com/questions/745059/systemd-causing-multiple-supervisor-processes. `forking one process per cpu`

Comment: try this command `pstree -gp`. This will show process tree with parent process id and process group id.